# Undoing Operation while editing in ArcMap with Python Add-ins?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, editing, python-addin, undo-redo

Using ArcPy Add-ins, I can issue a message, but I don’t understand how to cancel or undo deleting an object. Is it possible?

```py
class ControlUniq(object):
    """Implementation for addin1_addin.ControlUniq (Extension)"""
    def __init__(self):
        # For performance considerations, please remove all unused methods in this class.
        self.enabled = True
    def onDeleteFeature(self):
        chek=pythonaddins.MessageBox(u"Delete object?",u"Deleting...",1)
        print chek
        if chek=="OK":
            pythonaddins.MessageBox(u"The object was deleted",u"Deleting...")
        else:
            ### I don't understand how to undo operation Deleting
            ### Undo()
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Lora, your best bet will be using the arcpy data access Editor.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/editor.htm

With the Editor you can start, stop, undo and redo operations.

In short it operates very similar to the editing functionality found in the standard Editor toolbar in Arcmap.